# Pass the parameter only for non-empty variable in AJAX data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here I want to do which are the variable not empty, I want to pass that variable one in **data**,in this case area is empty so I want pass the parameter for city and listing type, but I don't know how to do?

```js
var city = "Karnadaka";
var area = "";
var listing type = "RENT";

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://www.domain.com/api/get/searchProperties",
    data: {
        area: area,
        city: city,
        listingType: listing_type
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Create an object, check if value is not empty then add to object `var data = {}; if (area) { data.area = area; } if (city) { data.city = city; } ...` And use this object to pass `data` to ajax request `data: data,`

Comment: From where i have to check this empty or not, can pls update your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var city = "Karnadaka";
var area = "";
var listing_type = "RENT";

var data = {};

if(city != '')
    data['city'] = city;

if(area != '')
    data['area'] = area;

if(listing_type != '')
    data['listing_type'] = listing_type;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://www.domain.com/api/get/searchProperties",
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yajnesh Rai @ your code is woking but while going dynamic it is not working that means area is ,i tried console.log(area) it is coming blank so that time it is not working what i have to do

Comment: Thanks @SagunthalaK. If there is any further requirement on dynamic code, please post that as well

Answer (score 1):

you can use `delete` to remove the propery pair(s) in an Object

```
var city = "Karnadaka";
var area = "";
var listing_type = "RENT";

var data={
        area: area,
        city: city,
        listingType: listing_type
    }

for (k in data){
    if(data[k]=="") delete data[k];
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://www.domain.com/api/get/searchProperties",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```